# Why to make extend exceptions in DAO?

Tags: java, api, exception, dao

I was reading up this code review questions [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/dao-layer-code-review) and tutorial by BalusC. In that I have found that exception classes are extended.

What is the need of it? I read something along the lines of `client layer should not know SQLExecption` but I am not sure I understand it.

Could you reason why to make specialized exceptions? What if my DAO method does not have `throws` and the client code is in a `try-catch`.?

Comment: Guess what is bad about the following: `throw new OhShitSomethingBadHappenedButIWontTellYouSpecificlyWhatException()`, apply that to your question, then delete your question.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That's really a scary message to client :)

Comment: That is good use of humour to get the point across!

Comment: it would probably get wrapped in a `try/catch and do nothing` block anyway, at least that is my experience in reading other peoples code over the last 17 years of doing Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because DAO could be today throw `SQLException` tomorrow if you want to change DAO layer to write to File, it might result in `FileNotFoundException`, So hiding underlying stuff you show to your client what matters to them (custom business sensible Exception)

Comment: Very concise and to the point! I should put more effort next time before asking easy questions.

Comment: I take this further and say, it shouldn't throw any `CheckedException` subclasses period!